How to run Telegram bot in separate thread, MacOS or Raspbian?
The following code runs without a problem in Windows 10, but I can't make it run in MacOS or Raspbian.
import logging
import asyncio
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, ContextTypes, CommandHandler
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

async def start_msg(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        print(f'chat_id: {update.effective_chat.id}')
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

async def get_chat_id(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"{update.effective_chat.id}")

async def hello( context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=5716168707, text="Starting bot")

key = open('../data/keys', 'r').read()
application = Application.builder().token(key).build()

job_queue = application.job_queue
job_queue.run_once(hello, 30)

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start_msg)
application.add_handler(start_handler)

chat_id = CommandHandler('get_chat_id', get_chat_id)
application.add_handler(chat_id)

def func():
    event_loop_a = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop_a)
    application.run_polling()


x = Thread(target=func)
x.start()

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

It gives the following error:
Exception in thread Thread-1 (func):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 105, in add_signal_handler
    signal.set_wakeup_fd(self._csock.fileno())
ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/workspace/code/bot_thread2.py", line 38, in func
    application.run_polling()
  File "/home/pi/workspace/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 838, in run_polling
    return self.__run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/workspace/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1028, in __run
    loop.add_signal_handler(sig, self._raise_system_exit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 107, in add_signal_handler
    raise RuntimeError(str(exc))
RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter
/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py:1040: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Updater.start_polling' was never awaited
  self._invoke_excepthook(self)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback


This looks like it a built-in limitation when running the bot on POSIX systems. Consider checking the bugtracker of the according project first and/or reporting a bug yourself. As a workaround, switch what you do in the "main" thread and what you do in the extra thread.
